# Is it possible to change Field Level Security with Workflows

Tags: workflow, permissions, roles, owd, fls

How can I show a hidden field to a user after triggering a workflow which will evaluate on certain condition and will decide either this field need to be visible or not?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change field level security by a workflow. However, you could do something like this:

1. Create a new record type for your object
2. Create a new page layout (on which you show this specific field) and assign it to the record type
3. Create a workflow rule based on your criteria + field update that changes the record type

Answer (score 0):

No its impossible to change field level security by workflow. **@robin** but i doubt your 3rd point since field should be hidden before workflow fire and you mentioned to include in pagelayout. ok but workflow only update field it doesn't hide or show field .and if you put hidden field in page layout than **Superman** condition is not fulfill

Workflow automates the following types of actions:

**Email Alerts**—Send an email to one or more recipients. For example, automatically send sales management an email alert when a sales representative qualifies a large deal.

**Tasks—Assign** a new task to a user, role, or record owner. For example, automatically assign follow-up tasks to a support representative one week after a case is updated.

**Field Updates**—Update the value of a field on a record. For example, automatically change the Owner field on a contract three days before it expires.

**Outbound Messages**—Send a secure configurable API message (in XML format) to a designated listener. For example, automatically initiate the reimbursement process for an approved expense report by triggering an outbound API message to an external HR system.

Comment: The field update should update the **record type**, not the field in question. This update will make sure a different page layout is shown, on which you can show the field.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt just to make my issue bit clear. I want to implement a functionality in which a user will ask a question and will save the answer of that question in salesforce. On answering the question workflow will compare the answer of the user with the original answer. And if it will be correct answer will be revealed to that particular user. And will remain hidden for rest of the users.

One idea that came into my mind is I use 'Field Update' with some static text in the field and update it after the workflow. I think this can work.

Comment: Could you use a Formula Field somehow to solve that? If the Answer and Solutions match than in the Formula Field display the "Correct" or similar output.